# POST url 403 forbidden in Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-403

Hi experts can you give me a suggestion, why I am getting this 403 forbidden on my code igniter currently running on my localhost.

[403 forbidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXlbQ.png)

---

The process is like this:

- I am using ajax for easy and smoothly access and retrieving of data from model, controller to the view the image below is my code in my views to controller.

  ```
  <div class="modal-header s-example-modal-sm" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
  ```

  ×
    New Question Modal
          
    
    
      function question_save(){

  ```
    $.ajax({
          url : "<?php echo base_url('Mainx/insert_question_header');?>",
          crossDomain: true,
          contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          method: "POST",
          data: { name: 'question_header'},
          dataType: 'json',
          '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>' : '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>',

          success: function(data){
              //alert('data save');
          },
          error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
              alert('Error adding');
          }
      });
  }
  ```

  Question Header:

---

And lastly from my controller and display the value that i type in my input under my view.

```
public function insert_question_header(){
    $insert_header = array(

        'question_header'=> $this->input->post("question_header")

    );
    //$this->db->insert('tb_question_header', $insert_header);
    echo json_encode($insert_header);
    redirect('Mainx/question_form/success' ); 
}
```

Comment: don't post ur code as image

Comment: sorry, my bad mate..

Comment: Just having trouble in that situation, i have already google for any possible answer but none of them answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

hey guys just found the answer. Thank you for all your suggestions and advice.

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function q_header() {

  var question = document.getElementById('question').value;

  $.ajax({
     url: "<?php echo base_url('Mainx/insert_question_header');?>",
     type: "post",
     data: {'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>':'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>',"question":question},
     success: function(){
       alert("success");
     },
     error:function(){
       alert("failure");
     }
  });

}


</script>
```

---

I try this code and instead using question_header i change it to question. This also work even when you set your $config[csrf_protection]=TRUE; or $config[csrf_generate]=TRUE;
this is my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

As in  [Docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf) Try with In your `Config` file Set

```
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: check ur file permissions @lothux1987 set it to 755

Comment: I have tried .htaccess and put it inside my application folder to allow access:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|js)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

Try it with this:

```
$.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo base_url('Mainx/insert_question_header');?>",
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        method: "POST",
        data: { name: 'question_header', '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>' : '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>' },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            //alert('data save');
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('Error adding');
        }
    });
```

So you have to place the *CSRF token* to the `data:` section.

Comment: You have an error in your controller, too. In the ajax function you post the `'name'`, and in the controller you want to use the `'question_header'` as posted element. So the right input: `'question_header' => $this->input->post("name")`

Comment: just change it as you said and still it wont work.. this gives me headache.

Comment: then try this in your controller: `$this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($insert_header));` instead of your `echo json_encode($insert_header);` and really remove that `redirect();`

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues here. First you are sending a parameter with the key "name" and value "question_header", and later you are referencing the input parameter by its value, not its name. This will not resolve the issue but is the first mistake.

Secondly, in your controller method, you are displaying some JSON data and calling `redirect` afterwards. This *could* be causing your error. If you push a redirect here, you will only redirect the AJAX call, and not the browser rendered page.

If you wish to redirect the visitor, you have to inform your AJAX response handler by outputting valid JSON that contains data for the redirect and then parse that JSON response and redirect with JavaScript.

Comment: I made some changes as others suggested to my post here..
if ( $this->input->is_ajax_request() ):
            $insert_header = array(

                'question_header'=> $this->input->post("name")

            );
            $this->db->insert('tb_question_header', $insert_header);

            echo json_encode($insert_header);
          
        endif;