# Ajax request with codeigniter 403 (forbidden)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to send an value with Ajax to Controller file in Codeigniter but without success.I have searched for that problem and i now this question is made many times here,but still can't find a sultion.Hope anyone can help me.
Thanks !

Js file.

```
function submitSend()
{
    var message = $('#sms').val();
    if(message == "")
    {
      $("#sms").attr("placeholder", "Type a message please...");
      return false;
    }

    $.ajax(
    {
      url: "<?php echo base_url();?>/mychat/send",
      type: 'POST',
      data:{
              '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>' : '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>',
              'message': message
             },
      success: function (data)
      {
       window.console.log('Successful');
      },
      error :function(data)
      {
      window.console.log('Failed');
      }
    });
}
```

Controller function.It's in file called MyChat.

```
public function send()
  {
     $message = $this->input->post('message');
     echo $message;
  }
```

Comment: And all you get is a 403? What error message is shown?

Comment: You might check my related answer on this through this 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36761009/post-url-403-forbidden-in-codeigniter-3)

Comment: @Alex now is not showing error,but when i try  'echo $message in controller file nothing is showing.Message variable is not passing to controller file.

Comment: @lothux1987 I have seen your answer ,my js code is ok now,but the variable message is not passing to controller file.I don't know why !

Comment: check devtools to see what is getting posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this code in your footer view before including JS file

```
<?php $CI =& get_instance(); ?>
<script> 
    var csrf_name = '<?php echo $CI->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>';
    var csrf_hash = '<?php echo $CI->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>';
</script>
```

and just call these variables anywhere you need like this

```
data:{
     csrf_name : csrf_hash,
     'message': message
},
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I  tried this method but does'nt work.The error removed only if include the js function inside view file.But still does'nt work correctly.The 'message' variable is not sent to controller file.

Comment: Add this varibable to footer too

`<script>
var base_url = "<?php echo base_url();?>";
</script>`
Then call it in your AJAX Function as 
`url: base_url+"/mychat/send",`

Comment: Still the same problem.

Comment: check your config file
`$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;`

Comment: ok use this in your footer 

`$CI =& get_instance(); // create codeigniter reference instance.`
and instead of `$this->security->` use `$CI->security->`

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't use `PHP` tags in `JavaScript` files, as you've mentioned you have a `JS` file.

You must run your `PHP` codes in **`.php`** files.

Perhaps you can decouple your `submitSend()` function a bit and make it more modular by extracting the `PHP` tags as well as `$('#sms').val()`. These can be passed to the function as parameters from where you call it **(`.php` files)**.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably its because of the CSRF token try disable csrf and check if its due to csrf then do whitelist the specific function in csrf config

Answer (score 0):

This work for me.

**/app/Config/Security.php**

```
/**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * CSRF Token Name
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * Token name for Cross Site Request Forgery protection cookie.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $tokenName = 'csrf_token_name';
```

**Inside my form**

```
<input type="hidden" name="<?= csrf_token() ?>" value="<?= csrf_hash() ?>" />
```

**in the script.js**

```
var tokenHash=jQuery("input[name=csrf_token_name]").val();
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "/somecontroller",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" },
beforeSend: function (xhr) 
        {       
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token' , tokenHash);       
        },
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    console.log( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

For Codeigniter 4

First, go to **app/Config/Security.php**

change

```php
public $regenerate = true;
```

To

```php
public $regenerate = false;
```

Note: Changing `$regenerate` to false is not good practice.

Second, go to **app/Config/Routes.php**
create your rout that you will call to preform request.

```php
$routes->post('url', 'ControllerName::FunctionName');
```

Then make sure u added `csrf_token()` and `csrf_hash()` to data you want to send.

So the code will look like this:

```php
var data= {
    "<?= csrf_token() ?>" : "<?= csrf_hash() ?>",// make sure this line exists
    something: "Something"
};

$.ajax({
        url: "<?= base_url('url_in_routes') ?>",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
            
        success: function (response){
            console.log("success");
                
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log("Error: " + error);
              
        },
        complete: function(data) {
            console.log(data.statusText);
        }
});
```

Controller:

```php
class Test extends BaseController{
    
    public function handleAjaxRequest(){
        $something = $this->request->getPost('something');
        // Now u can use $something to save it to ur DB or do what you want.
    }
    
}
```

Other thing in Codeigniter is that when a **request fails** the CSRF validation check, it will redirect to the previous page by default so the user can not see the error to turn it off, go to **app/Config/Security.php**

change

```php
 public $redirect = true;
```

to

```php
 public $redirect = false;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't use php tag in js file

```
url: "<?php echo base_url();?>/mychat/send", //this line in js file is wrong
```

You only use php tag in script tag in .php file like this

```
<script>
 // ... some code here 
     url: "<?php echo base_url();?>/mychat/send",
 // ... some code here
</script>
```

Or add this line in header html

```
<script> 
    var BASE_URL = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>';
</script>
```

and use it in js file

```
....
url: BASE_URL+"mychat/send",
....
```

Comment: I set the function that is in js file inside view file.Now is not show any error but nothing is sent in controller file where i send the  variable message.I can't understand why ?!

Comment: variable message is getting value from html successfully,but don't pass it to controller file

Comment: Because the url is wrong
You can't use <?php echo base_url();?> in js file, the message post to the wrong controller